# Can't get commands to work in Mirror Network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, mirror

Recently hopped on Mirror Networking and having some troubles with commands

So, I have some blocks that are instantiated at runtime and they can be clicked.

My logic is that when block is clicked, then i send a message to a server with id of the block, then server through a game manager, which has list of all blocks, perform a click on the block with that id for each client, using ClientRpc.

This is working just fine on the host instance, but not on the client one.

The code is simple

```
 [Command(requiresAuthority = false)]
public void SendClickToAServer(int index)
{
     Debug.Log("Clicked index:" + index);
}
```

But I'm having an error and client gets disconnected
I need to send a message to a server from client, so I'm using command. When I try to do it on host instance, then every thing is fine, but when i try to send this message from just client then i'm getting an error Disconnecting connection: connection(390227533) because handling a message of type Mirror.CommandMessage caused an Exception. This can happen if the other side accidentally (or an attacker intentionally) sent invalid data. Reason: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Mirror.NetworkServer.OnCommandMessage (Mirror.NetworkConnectionToClient conn, Mirror.CommandMessage msg, System.Int32 channelId) [0x00103] in \Mirror\Core\NetworkServer.cs:327

I add all needed components and inheritance, as I said on the host instance it is working, i just can not get what object reference is missing. Maybe there is problem with the way i instantiate or spawn objects?

If i remove [Command] then every thing works fine, but it is hot synced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. It's hard for me to tell what's wrong, but there's nothing wrong with the code you provided (nor with your workflow).

If it is running fine on the *host* and not the *client* then you have an issue where your *client* is handling an incorrect `NetworkIdentity` (most likely) and the state of the game is already out of sync before you send the `Command`. Check to make sure that the objects you are spawning are spawned on the *server* and synced to the *client* (rather than spawning a `NetworkIdentity` directly on the *client*). Make sure you aren't spawning the `Player Prefab` twice as well as they get created by the `NetworkManager` by default when connecting to the *server* (as in, make sure they're not already in your scene before launching the *server*).

Comment: That's starting to make sense for me...

Currently i'm instantiating it that way
Tile instantiated = Instantiate(tile).GetComponent<Tile>();
NetworkServer.Spawn(instantiated.gameObject);

As i understood the problem is here, maybe i didn't get what Spawn() is doing.

It would be veeeeeery helpful if you could provide a bit of code. But you already helped me a lot, I'll try to make some changes soon and will reply here again.

Comment: Glad we we're able to make some progress! I would love to provide code, but I still have no idea what the real issue is without seeing your own code :( 
When you get the exception error, are you sure the `NetworkConnectionToClient` you are referencing is valid? It appears to be null on the *server*. As an aside, make sure you spawn things directly from your `NetworkManager`'s registered prefabs. Does you have your `Tile` `GameObject` have a `NetworkIdentity` and have you added its prefab to the `NetworkManager`'s `Registered Spawnable Prefabs`?

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about the Registered Spawnable Prefabs, in the console it was no errors regarding it, BIG thanks! 
Also another thing i got wrong is that i Instantiated and object and immediately spawned it and them manipulated it, thinking it would behave just as standart object.

So, adding prefab to Registered Spawnable Prefabs
Spawn object on server when I've done all manipulations needed.

That solved my problem, thanks again!

Comment: woo! glad it worked!